# Dealing with problematic killer DM?

Tags: dnd-3.5e

I have a problem with the GM of the d&d game we're playing. To give you an idea of whats going on our group consists of me (gnoll paladin/cleric/fist of raziel) luka (monk/barbarian) doug (wizard) ashley (bard/ranger) and the GM. we're playing an undead heavy campaign and everything was going well until recently when I confided in the dm (who is my close friend) something about myself since i ws going through some hard times and now lately it seems like every session has been more focused on trying to kill off my character than anything else.

Just an example: we were in a sand crypt looking to recover a lost ring that the high priestess of the jade had lost while on an emissary mission and the cave was full of vampires. I led the way and we stumbled across a chamber where they were all sleeping. we backed out of the room and I had the party put enhancement spells on me so I could deal with the vampires, but for some reason when I went in the room the dm started making me roll move silent checks. I rolled a 6 and all the vampires suddenly woke up and started attacking me while I was in the middle of the room before the others could get in. All of them were swarming me and I was getting lucky that they couldn't hit through my AC (most were rolling on average 16) but then suddenly one hits me with a critical hit and I take a negative level. Okay thats fine. We kill the vampires and I drink a healing potion, but the DM tells me that the negative level didn't go away. I wind up having to back track all the way to the temple just to get it removed, and by the time we got back, THE VAMPIRES HAD ALREADY REFORMED IN THEIR COFFINS AND WERE PERFECTLY FINE.

Proof 2: Going into a desert temple where signs of a battle had taken place, there's a strange old man coming out of it dressed completely different from everyone we'd met so far. I detect evil on him and the DM tells me that I'm overwhelmed by his evil aura, so much so that I'm stunned for a round and get a nose bleed. I don't even get a save against this, he just gets to freely attack me for no reason whatsoever. Then to add insult to injury the old man turns out to be a dry lich who just laughs at me, tells me that I'd be best to leave this place, then strolls off without even fighting us. I go look up the stat block later that evening for the Dry Lich and it turns out it's a really powerful monster! How the hell am I supposed to deal with a monster that can literally cheat and stun me for no reason whatsoever?

The final straw: Game night comes and I get separated from the party when we're raiding a tomb, and fall down a trapdoor. Lo and behold I land in a chamber with a giant armored undead spider thing that starts kicking my ass. I try to turn tail and run and get out of there but the thing is faster than me (somehow, which doesn't make sense I'm a gnoll running fast is something I should be able to do well) and I get webbed and strung from the ceiling. Now I'm probably going to die next session from whatever insane crap the DM is cooking up while the rest of the party is upstairs looting and whatnot.

All of this seems to have started because I was feeling bad and wanted someone to talk to so I talked to my dm (who is my friend) and told him that I wasn't feeling too good and I was unhappy with my character because it's not as strong as everyone else's. Just because I want to be stronger doesn't mean the DM should be going out of his way to kill me for no reason. That's why I'm here, does anyone have any advice on how I could beat the DM at his own game? Ways I could do really tricky things to just one-up whatever garbage he throws at me? He's a good friend but as a DM this is just insane that he's trying to kill me off just because I'm playing a gnoll that happens to be similar to my avatar/persona. I don't appreciate him doing this and I just want to show him that what he's doing is not right and if I can beat him at his own game it will probably be the best thing to do.

Comment: Please do not answer in comments.

Comment: One thing that leapt out at me that differs this question from the duplicate is your last paragraph. You complained to the DM that you were unhappy with your character. I'd imagine he's trying to kill your character off to give you the opportunity to remake it. He seems to just be trying to do this within the rules, possibly to avoid the other PCs all wanting to reroll as well.

Comment: Most of those "negative GM behaviors" seem pretty fine to me (provided you two want to play the same game): to me the examples you brink make this a pretty different question, with different answers, than the one marked as duplicate.